# StdIn, How to read strings separated by spaces without stuck in infinite loop waiting for more user input

Tags: java, string, input, while-loop, stdin

I am working on a program that requires me to take user's input of Strings separated with spaces and print those strings out in random order again.  I have been told to use StdIn.readString() method for taking the user's input.

I soon realized that readString() method only reads the first token and stops.  So I assume that I would need a while loop to keep on reading until user has finished keying in all the Strings.  I thought of creating a while loop with the breaking condition of StdIn.isEmpty() being true to break the loop but found out that once user started key in value, it always returns "True".  Thus I am stuck in the infinite loop of waiting for user to key in more Strings.

The javadoc for the StdIn is here:  http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/javadoc/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/StdIn.html#readString()

The simplified code is below:

```
public static void main(String args[])  {
/*
 * This is placeholder, I do not know how long the user input String is.
 */    
String[] s = new String[10];
int index = 0;    
    while(StdIn.isEmpty())  {
        s[index] = StdIn.readString();
        index++;
    }
}

// from here I would like to do other actions, but I cannot break the while loop
```

I know for reading in Integers or Doubles, people tend to set a sentinel value, but I am not sure what sentinel value to set for reading in Strings.  Looking forward to your help, many thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know when the user is done?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use readString()? Using a Scanner would probably be easier because it gives you more options

Comment: Try using `Scanner` and reading a full line, or if you're input exists on multiple lines, you'll have to find some way to have the user indicate when to stop. I'm not familiar with the `StdIn` class, but it probably has a readLine method as well.

Comment: Your `StdIn` has a `readLine()` method, maybe it would help .

Comment: If you absolutely have to use StdIn class, perhaps you can use .readLine() method which presumably will return you a line containing space separated `words` which then you can split into an array?

Comment: I have to use StdIn, let me give the readLine() a shot.

Comment: But this assignment absolutely said readString() should be used, I feel like writing a word parser with readLine() is a work around but might not be the most direct?

Comment: If you need to use the readString() method, as your first paragraph implies, then a sentinel value probably is your best bet. We can't really tell you what the value should be, because that depends on the domain of your project. It can really be any value that isn't otherwise a valid input string, in however the business rules of your project determine a valid input string.

Comment: @tradeJmark is correct. Use his advice.

Answer (score 3):

"To do so, depending on your operating system and IDE, use either Ctrl+d or Ctrl+z" from http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html